# Install Windows 10 with Boot Camp on Big Sur not starting installer

Tags: windows, bootcamp, usb

I am trying to install Windows 10 (ISO downloaded from the official site) in my MacBook Pro Mid 2014 (MacBookPro11,1) running Big Sur 11.2.3. I've used Boot Camp to create a USB 2.0 bootable drive with the Windows image and created BOOTCAMP partition but when macOS restarts to begin Windows installation it fails: Windows logo appears for a couple of seconds, then goes black, macOS chime plays and system restarts.

If I restart pressing `Alt` then I can see "EFI Boot" and "BOOTCAMP" drives, but not working if selecting any of them.

I've also tried creating the image with UNetbootin, but same.

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've managed to do it. These are the steps in case anyone faces same issue:

1. Start Boot Camp with a USB 2.0 (important, not 3.0) plugged in
2. Check all three options (create USB stick, download Windows support files, create partition)
3. After Boot Camp finishes it will restart but ignore it (if you are reading this I guess it is failing)
4. Safely unplug the USB stick and go to a **Windows** machine
5. Open a browser and download the **Windows 10 Media Creation Tool** from the official website
6. Insert the USB drive and create the USB bootable stick using that tool.
7. When done, go to your Mac computer, plug in the USB stick and start the computer pressing `Alt` key
8. It should appear the startup disk selection with three options: macOS, EFI Boot (yellow, this is the USB stick) and BOOTCAMP (the partition Boot Camp Assistant created). At this point this could differ from my experience but booting "EFI Boot" does not work, first I had to boot "BOOTCAMP", it will fail because there is no disk to start and when computer restarts, press `Alt` again and then boot "EFI Boot". Don't know why but I had to follow that sequence in order to get this to work.
9. If everything is OK Windows installer should start and the installation will finish without errors.
10. Probably you won't be able to connect to WiFi, modify screen resolution, right clicking with the touchpad, etc. That is because you have to install the Windows Support files, so go back to macOS.
11. Open Boot Camp Assistant and select Action menu in the toolbar > Download Windows Support Software. When done, copy the folder "WindowsSupport" to the previously used USB stick (could be another but just make sure Windows could read it)
12. Go back to Windows, open "WindowsSupport" folder in the USB and start "setup.exe".
13. When done, you would be able to connect to the Internet, modify screen resolution, etc.

And that's all. Hope it helps!